# Does middle lane experience range reach the wraith camp?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does the allied jungler at wraith camp receive shared experience when the enemy minions push and die to the turret in middle lane?

Comment: Pretty sure they can, but they might have to sit inside where the camp spawns. I've done it before to get to the next level, I believe, when close. You might only get exp from the closer minions. I don't have proof, and I don't know the radius - which is why this is a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**.

> Experience from minion deaths is split between all champions within 1600 range.

1600 is actually a pretty long range. As an example, Nocturne's and Caitlyn's ultimates have 2000 range at level 6. Turrets have 775 attack range.

Sources :

- http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_%28champion%29
- http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Turret

Comment: nice.. time to camp wraiths now lol

Comment: To add some clarity to what 1600 range equates to: Caitlin's base attack range is 360.  So 1600 range is about 4.4 times the range of Caitlin's auto-attack.

Comment: @Lumberjack: Where did you find this value (360)? Caitlyn's actual attack range is 650, so it would be more like 2.4 times her range. 360 attack range would be awfully small for a marksman, Urgot has the smallest one (425) and some melee champions can reach 325 attack range (Aatrox and Hecarim). See http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Range

Answer (score 0):

Short answer **NO**.

Minions are lane-only; MONSTERS are in the jungle (and dragon/baron). Monster XP is very localized BECAUSE of the problem your post presents -- it used to be possible to steal wraith XP from being too close in midlane. Now it's impossible, the range is very close for jungle XP (also to help with leashing at low skill levels!)

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, though. It answers a good followup question, i.e. the converse of this one. I'm personally not sure how likely it is that this post will stay here.

Comment: @Schism ahh I misread